# magento 2: Add custom <script> tag in <head> section, only for specific CMS page

Tags: magento2, cms-pages, script, head

I have a CMS page in Magento 2, for which I want to add `<script>` tag that will be included in the `<head>` section of this page only.

I do not want this `<script>` tag to appear on any other page.
My Magento version is 2.4.2

Thank you in advance !!

Answer (score 0):

You have to create a layout file specifically for your CMS Page, such as in layout folder of your custom module,

```
cms_page_view_selectable_<CMS Page Identifier>_<Layout Update Name>.xml
```

for example if my CMS page identifier name is testing, I'll name it as **cms_page_view_selectable_testing_loginform.xml** and inside the file I can write code as below to get the login form and remember me option as well:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
-->
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="1column" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <head>
        <link src="[Vendor]_[Module]::js/js_fileName.js"/>
    </head>
</page>
```

And than go to your CMS page in admin and from there under design tab, select your option in Custom Layout Update, whatever you've named it, here I have named it loginform, so I'll select loginform inside my Custom Layout Update.